# Anyone know of a solid .NET Framework 2.0 installer script for Inno Setup?

Tags: .net, windows, .net-2.0, installation, inno-setup

I've spent a good part of the day searching, writing and finally scrapping a script that I can use with my Inno Setup install script that will download and install the appropriate .NET 2.0 Framework if needed.

There are definitely a number of examples out there, but they:

1. Want to install Internet Explorer if needed which I wouldn't dare to in an automated way
2. Only handle x86 .NET distributions, no x64 and IA64 support
3. Don't install the appropriate language pack when needed -- a tough problem (when I saw there were different language packs for different x86/x64/language combos I threw in the towel)
4. Don't handle getting the .NET 2.0 SP1 (maybe Windows Update will handle that once 2.0 is installed?)

This seems like such a common problem that *someone* must have solved it.  All I found though were 20 different posts all pointing to the same two or three code snippets.

Insight welcomed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[.NET Framework 1.1/2.0/3.5 Installer for InnoSetup](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/dotnetfx_innosetup_instal.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I have recently been looking into this issue but without the same requirements that you have.  I haven't seen a script that does what you want but have you considered instead checking if .NET 2.0 is installed and if not then prompt them to download it.  You can open a URL in the default browser and get the user to attempt the install again once the framework has been installed.

This is not an ideal situation from a user perspective but i think going with what your planning you will have to write some complex stuff to handle the different language constraints just to get it working.

Just my 2 cents.